# AndroidStudio アクセス許可に明示していない権限が表示される

Tags: android-studio, google-play

現在AndroidStudio2.1.2にてアプリを作成中なのですが、googlePlayでインストールする時にAndroid Manifestには明示していない権限が求められるのを削除したいと思っています。

削除したい権限は「位置情報」です。

以下Android Manifestの一部です。

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" /> 
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />

<application...
```

以下のリンクも確認しましたが、今回のケースではどうなるのかわからなかったため質問致しました。

1.
[AndroidStudio アクセス許可に、求めた覚えのない権限を求める](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/20314/androidstudio-%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9%E8%A8%B1%E5%8F%AF%E3%81%AB-%E6%B1%82%E3%82%81%E3%81%9F%E8%A6%9A%E3%81%88%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E6%A8%A9%E9%99%90%E3%82%92%E6%B1%82%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B/20330)

2.
対処法: 不必要なPermissionが勝手に追加されてるとき
http://android.tecc0.com/?p=161

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

同様の事で悩んでいる方が解決方法を提示されておりましたのでリンク貼っておきます。

[【Android】アプリに不要なパーミッションが追加されているときの対処法](https://cpoint-lab.co.jp/%E3%80%90android%E3%80%91%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%81%AB%E4%B8%8D%E8%A6%81%E3%81%AA%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9F%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%8C%E8%BF%BD%E5%8A%A0%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C/)

上記サイトによると、解除方法は以下の３つとのこと。

１．targetSdkVersion を更新
２．LibraryのtargetSdkVersion を更新
３．AndroidManifest.xmlで上書きして削除

上記を記述された方は、"android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE "で発生したとのことです。

Answer (score 0):

良い方法かは分かりませんが

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" />
```

をして強制的に削除してみてはどうでしょうか？